# Why converting an integer to a float is slower than calculating its square root?

Tags: python, floating-point

I got the following result when experimenting with IPython:

```
In [10]: %timeit float(127.7)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 173 ns per loop

In [11]: %timeit math.sqrt(127.7)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 127 ns per loop

In [12]: %timeit float(19847)
1000000 loops, best of 3: 181 ns per loop

In [13]: %timeit math.sqrt(19847)
10000000 loops, best of 3: 145 ns per loop
```

As you can see, `float` is slower even when the parameter IS a already float.

Comment: `float()` can't know that the argument is already a `float`.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams Would you please tell me the reason? It seems to me like it's possible to detect type of Python objects in the C-API level.

Comment: You're looking at the wrong level. Try the compiler.

Comment: The `float` conversion is slower no matter whether the parameter is an integer or not.

Comment: Think of it this way: When does the conversion to float happen in each of cases 2 and 3?

Comment: How consistent are the times if you rerun one of the earlier tests?